# How to use Vuex through the setup function in Storybook

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, storybook, vuex4

I am currently struggling with Vuex in Storybook. I use it through `const store = useStore()` in the `setup` function.

However I didn't find a way to inject a custom store into the component.

I can surely inject a store globally in the storybook `preview.js` config file as follow:

```js
import { app } from '@storybook/vue3';
import store, { key } from '@/store';

app.use(store, key);
```

Is there a way to create custom stores for stories of components that are using the composition API (useStore() to get to Vuex) ?

Comment: Actually, Pinia should be used with vue 3 :)